# Autosys Permission options

Tags: unix, autosys

As per the Autosys manual, the following permission options can be configured in the JIL file:

gx,ge,wx,we,mx,me

Can someone please explain what each of these options represent?

I tried searching the web but could not get any help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `x` and `e` refer to the rights to execute and edit, respectively. Execute here essentially means change the status of the job - start, force start, put on ice, kill, delete, etc.

The `g`, `w`, and `m` refer to who has the ability to perform those actions. `w` specifies that the world (anyone) has rights, the `g` specifies that any user who is in the same group as the job owner has rights, and `m` specifies that authorized users have permissions regardless of what machine they are on. By default, when `m` is not used, the user must be on the machine specified in the owner field of the job.

For example, giving the job gx,wx,ge means that anyone on that machine may change the status of the job, but only users in the same group as the owner may edit it.

Comment: @goric , Incase of `mx` Can you please help me understand what exactly you mean by authorized users. Is there any command to fetch the list of users who have permission ?